# "No Such File" error on Node.js AWS Lambda function that used to work

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Working with AWS Lambda in Cloud9. This code used to work:

```js
    var fs = require('fs');

    module.exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
        var response = {};
        
        var page = fs.readFileSync('public/header.html', 'utf8');
```

After updating the Node.js runtime to nodejs18.x and redeploying the function, I now get the error:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'public/header.html'

I have tried all possible variations of the filename to match the file tree, as well as using `path.join(__dirname)` to try to get the location at runtime, and nothing has fixed it.

To add some context, the public folder contains a bunch of template HTML. The functions read those templates, insert the results, then kick it back to the user.

Other functions that were NOT updated are still working correctly, using that same syntax.

I know that Cloud9 changed how it was doing deployments; could that have broken the file read? Other suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Use the `fs` functions to list the folders in the current working directory and to list their file contents. And check that the redeployed function ZIP package actually contained public/header.html.

Comment: In addition to jarmod's suggestion above, 'and redeploying the function' is probably the key here and not 'updating the Node.js runtime to nodejs18.x'.